# Validating a nested XML element with an empty namespace using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate a bunch XML file that looks roughly like this (an example [full file](https://gist.github.com/jpluimers/6407106) is at Gist):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- ... -->
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <Borland.Personality>Default.Personality</Borland.Personality>
    <Borland.ProjectType />
    <BorlandProject>
  <BorlandProject xmlns=""> <Default.Personality> </Default.Personality> </BorlandProject></BorlandProject>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- ... -->
</Project>
```

I know the nested `<BorlandProject xmlns="">` is odd, but a lot of those XML files in our repository are that way and I want to validate them OK.

The files use a subset of the MSBuild definition. So far I've tried something like this (again: [full file](https://gist.github.com/jpluimers/6407096) in on Gist):

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
  targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Project" type="ProjectType"/>
  <!-- ... -->
  <xsd:complexType name="ProjectExtensionsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Borland.Personality" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Borland.ProjectType" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="BorlandProject" type="BorlandProjectType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="BorlandProjectType">
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Default.Personality" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="BorlandProject" type="BorlandProjectType"/>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!-- ... -->
</xsd:schema>
```

Validating barfs with an error message like this:

```
Error: The element 'BorlandProject' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'  
has invalid child element 'BorlandProject'.  
List of possible elements expected:   
'Default.Personality, BorlandProject' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'.  
<BorlandProject>
```

I think this is because of the odd `xmlns=""` inside `<BorlandProject xmlns="">`.

Two questions:

1. Is my `xmlns=""` assumption right?
2. How can I validate this `<BorlandProject xmlns="">` element?

*Edit*

Thanks *ColdFusion* for his answer. This is what I finally did, as the `BorlandProject` can both be qualified and unqualified:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="BorlandProjectType">
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Default.Personality" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <!-- Delphi <= 2010 can have a nested `BorlandProject` element, sometimes unqualified (with xmlns=""), sometimes qualified -->
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="BorlandProject" form="unqualified" type="BorlandProjectTypeUnqualified"/>
        <xsd:element name="BorlandProject" type="BorlandProjectTypeQualified"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="BorlandProjectTypeUnqualified">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Default.Personality" form="unqualified" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="BorlandProjectTypeQualified">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Default.Personality" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my xmlns="" assumption right?

Yes. Having `xmlns=""` is nothing wrong. The "" is also a namespace -- the global one (or "nonamespace").

> How can I validate this  element?

The elements in nonamespace are called **unqualified**.

As long as all elements, which you need to be unqualified, are local ones (that is nested in some other elements), that can be specifically declared (for each particular element) using `form="unqualified"` attribute.

**Note:** Whether **all** local elements (defined in the schema) are qualified or not is specified with `elementFormDefault` attribute
in `<xsd:schema>`. But you can mix it, so as to have some local elements qualified and some not.

For instance, your XML file (provided in your question) can be validated against this schema:

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  version="1.0"
  targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:element name="Project" type="ProjectType"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="ProjectType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="ProjectExtensions" type="ProjectExtensionsType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <!-- ... -->
  <xsd:complexType name="ProjectExtensionsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Borland.Personality" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Borland.ProjectType" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="BorlandProject" type="BorlandProjectType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="BorlandProjectType">
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Default.Personality" type="xsd:string"
                     form="unqualified"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="BorlandProject" type="BorlandProjectType"
                   form="unqualified"/>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!-- ... -->
</xsd:schema>
```

Note that according to that schema you actually have two `BorlandProject` elements: one in `http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003` and another one in no namespace. I don't know, whether you really need this... But that's how your XML is written.

Comment: +1, accepted. Thanks. This got me in the right direction. See the edit to my question I just made: the `BorlandProject` can occur both qualified and unqualified. I know having that is not good practice, but those files are a given.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, after removing the xmlns="" the XML validates.
2. a) The simplest solution would be to remove the invalid xmlns from the XML.

   b) Harder would be to have another schema  which you import that has no namespace that defines another the BorlantProjectType which you can reference.  I tried this and couldn't get it to work.

   c) Another possibility is to generate a new schema based on the XML and then validate against that.  I did that and then tweaked it a bit the get the nesting in the include happening.  However as this was just tested against one sample it may need some more tweaking.
   XSDs here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6408209 & https://gist.github.com/Dijkgraaf/6408223

EDIT:
   d) Go with the answer ColdFusion gave which is a lot simpler.

Comment: +1; Thanks for confirming it was indeed the `xmlns=""`. I cannot change the XML files (they are a given). So I went with ColdFusion's answer.